Non magic boy gets magic from dragon bite
I am looking for a book I read a while ago but never got to finished.
It was set in a world of magic and the main character was a boy who didn't have magic. He went to a magic school and is treated terribly by a teacher who is trying to "force the magic" to arise in him. At one point he is left in a dark closet which doesn't work.
Finally the teacher drags him through a portal and leaves him far far away saying he'll have to open a portal himself if he ever wants to come back.
There is a scene where the boy ends up facing a dragon. The boy lunges forward and stabs a sword through the roof of the dragon's mouth and the dragon bites into his arm. The dragons blood makes it into the boy's arm.
Later the big wakes up and the dragon complains that it is trying to kill him but that for some reason it can't attack him no matter how hard it tries. The boy surmises that the dragon blood joined them together and the dragon can't personally hurt him.
The dragon then grabs the boy and flies high into the air and lets him fall thinking that maybe it can kill him if it doesn't strike the killing blow.
The boy falls and desperately tries to grab onto something to slow himself down. It is now that he notices he can see the fabric of the world around him as little strings. He pulls as the strong and begins to pull a cloud in beneath him to soften the fall but it's too late and he impacts the water below him hard.
When he wakes up he is being cared for by an old fisherman who saved him and he can hear the dragon talking to him in his mind.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?  Do you remember the cover art?

5-10 years ago and I'm not about the cover. I'm almost positive it was a digital book.
